# How to remove OCTAL character using Linux?

Tags: vim, replace

I have a large file that I need to edit in Linux.
the file has data fields enclosed by double quotes ( "" ). But when I open the file using notepad++ I see SOH character between the double quotes `(ie. "filed1"SOH"field2"SOHSOH"field3"SOH"field4")`

And when I open the same file in vim I see the double quotes followed by ^A character.  `(ie. "filed1"^A"field2"^A^A"field3"^A"field4")`

Then when I execute this command in the command line

```
cat filename.txt | od -c | more
```

I see that the character is shown as 001 (ie. "filed1"001"field2"001001"field3"001"field4")

I have tried the following via vim

```
:s%/\\001//g
```

I also tried this command

```
sed -e s/\001//g filename.text > filename_new.txt
sed -e s/\\001//g filename.text > filename_new.txt
```

I need to remove those characters from that file.
How can I do that?

Comment: Also, when you have a file written by some text editor it windows and you open it in linux, you can get some weird characrers in it. For such file you are better off using `dos2unix <filename>` command to take care of the weird characters. For the opposite case, use `unix2dos <filename>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use echo -e to get a literal \001 character into your sed command:

```
$ sed -i -e $(echo -e 's/\001//g') file.txt
```

(-i is a GNU sed extension to request in-place editing.)

Comment: This worked. Can you please explain to me what did you do? I am new to lunix so I will appreciate it if you explain the line.

Comment: You need to get a literal \001 (i.e. one character, ASCII value 1) into the sed command, rather than some variation of the string "\001" (i.e. several characters). echo -e is a shell command that prints its argument having converted \ooo to characters with octal value ooo (in our case 001 = ASCII 1), so the echo command will print out the desired sed command. The $(...) construct means "run the ... command, and substitute the output into this command", hence sed sees the echo output, which is the desired command, complete with embedded \001 character.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempts at escaping the SOH character with `\001` were close.

GNU sed has an extension to specify a decimal value with `\d001` (there are also octal and hexadecimal variants):

```
$ sed -i -e 's/\d001//g' file.txt
```

In Vim, the regular expression atom looks slightly different: `\%d001`; alternatively, you can directly enter the character in the `:%s` command-line via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed by `001`; cp. `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`.

Answer (score 0):

just keep it simple with `awk` instead of having to fuss with quotation formatting issues :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='\1' OFS=
> ```

```
 "filed1""field2""field3""field4"
```